# is any preview of the IJ component of the XYZ IJ point cloud data of the Google tango project available?

Tags: unity-game-engine, point-cloud-library, google-project-tango

I would like to make use of the ij component of the XYZij point cloud, but according to the latest known issues document this feature is still in development.  is there anyway I could acquire early access to a beta version of this feature or implement my own comparable version?

what I'm really going for is the point cloud as a zbuffer to mask off ocluded objects in an AR game i am working on.  if there is another way to achieve that, that would work too.  I'm using Unity (5.1.3f personal) and I'm following the Augmented Reality sample.

currently I get the depth at a given screen point and it checks every point in the point cloud and this is inefficient for checking more than one point per frame.  but if the depth at that point is less than the depth of the virtual element I can know that it's not visible.  however the effect is not smooth around corners and naturally would be nice to be able to check more than one point per frame.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Matt, the IJ is still not available, really sorry about that.. But for Unity SDK, we are releasing an occlusion example in next release. The implementation is actually simpler than using the IJ method. In short, what we did is rendering the point cloud as one render pass, but only render it to depth buffer, then we let the point cloud depth buffer and the actually geometry depth buffer to do the depth test, then the graphic pipeline will take care of the occlusion, and etc.

Comment: great, thanks. That sounds like exactly what I want to do.  for now I'll just stick with my approach of checking one point each frame from a queue.  It's probably a lot slower than what you described, but good enough for testing while I work on art assets and gameplay.  Btw It would be great if that same depth buffer object could also be used as a shadow receiver.  Thanks for answering.